# How to make columns in listbox?

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I want to implement into my listbox columns (marked purple) like in the picture below:

[image]

Main window in my gui is divided into two tabs. I paste here only code from tab into which I want to implement columns. Listbox is already here:

```
tab1_layout = [
                    [sg.Listbox(values=list_of_workers, size=(15, 7), key='-WORKERS_LISTBOX-', select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_EXTENDED),
                        sg.Button('', image_data=convert_to_bytes(cogwheel_icon, (30, 30)), border_width=5, key='cogwheel', tooltip='Workers options')],
                    [sg.Button('', image_data=convert_to_bytes(plus_icon, (30, 30)), border_width=5, key='plus', tooltip='Add worker'),
                        sg.Button('', image_data=convert_to_bytes(minus_icon, (30, 30)), border_width=5, key='minus', tooltip='Delete worker'),
                        sg.Button('Delete all', size=(8,3))]
                   ]
```

Comment: The screenshot is not of a Listbox Element.  It's a Table Element.

Comment: My mistake. Anyway the question is still valid.

Comment: It's sorta not though.  You're asking how to duplicate the purple portion of the window by using Listboxes.  Was simply trying to avoid disappointment since that's not how the window was created.

Comment: Nevermind, thanks to your "hint" that it is Table Element I already found the solutions.